# Code is not working, and is not doing directed task

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, c-strings, string-literals

The code is self explanatory, but I need help because, when I use it, it skips all the "If" cases and jumps to the next loop directly. The "scanf" works correctly; the variable "order" receives input correctly too. If you figure out how to fix it, Let me know! Have a great day!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int side [3]; // Fries(0), Fried Squid(1), Cheese Fries(2)
    int combo [3]; // Spicy Chicken(0), Whopper(1), Double Whopper(2)
    int drinks[3]; // Cola(0), Vanilla Shake(1), Lemonade(2)
    int amount;
    char order [20];
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        combo[i] = 20;
        total = total + 20;
    }
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        side[i] = 20;
        total = total + 20;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        drinks[i] = 20;
        total = total + 20;
    }

    while (total > 0){
        printf("Make your order here: \n");
        scanf("%s %d", order, &amount);
        printf("%s\n", order);
        if(order == "Fries"){
            printf("A\n");A
            if(side[0] < amount){
                printf("Your order is invalid, and you are stinky.\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("B\n");
                printf("your order is here: %s x %d", order, amount);
                total = total - amount;
            }
            printf("C\n");
        }
        printf("D\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the rest of the IF statements to simplify the code! Have a good one!

Comment: You need to use something like `strcmp` to compare strings. `==` is comparing pointers, not data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja TYSM! It worked! Blessings of the holdiays to you! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in if statements like this

```
if(order == "Fries"){
```

does not make a sense. There are compared two pointers and it is evident that they have different values. That is the character array `order` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and the string literal is also implicitly converted to a pointer the same way.

Pay attention to that if you will even write for example

```
if("Fries" == "Fries"){
```

then it is not necessary that the expression will evaluate to the logical true. The result of the expression depends on a compiler option that is whether the compiler stores identical string literals as one string literal or as different string literals.

What you need is to compare two strings like

```
#include <string.h>

// ...

if( strcmp( order, "Fries" ) == 0 ){
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot test now but I think you should use `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare strings; the `==` operator will compare only the pointer.